SQL query get slower and slower while load testing
I'm currently loading a Spring Boot application with Spring Data JPA which connected to a PostgreSQL database. There is a Rest API to get sample details for a given time period. That API is working fine for single request which give the paginated response around 500ms. However, noticed that while performing the load on that API, response time goes high.
Please find the following repository code snippet which is responsible for querying data.
@Query(value = """
        select
          to2.sample_number as sampleNumber,
          ta.profile_id    as fromAgentProfileId,
          ta.full_name     as fromAgentName,
          ta2.profile_id   as toAgentProfileId,
          ta2.full_name    as toAgentName,
          to2.sample_type   as sampleTypeId,
          tp.id            as brandId,
          tp.name          as brandName,
          tod.price        as price,
          to2.created_date as createdDate
        FROM tbl_sample_detail tod
          JOIN tbl_sample to2 ON tod.sample_id = to2.id
          JOIN tbl_user ta ON to2.from_user_id = ta.id
          JOIN tbl_user ta2 ON to2.to_user_id = ta2.id
          JOIN tbl_brand tp on tod.brand_id = tp.id
        WHERE
          (ta.profile_id = :profileId OR ta2.profile_id = :profileId)
          AND (-1 = :userId OR to2.from_user_id = :userId OR to2.to_user_id = :userId)
          AND (-1 IN :sampleTypeList OR to2.sample_type IN :sampleTypeList)
          AND (-1 IN :brandIds OR tod.brand_id IN :brandIds)
          AND (-1 IN :brandCategoryIds OR tp.brand_category_id IN :brandCategoryIds)
          AND to2.created_date between :fromTime and :toTime
        ORDER BY to2.created_date DESC
        """, nativeQuery = true, countQuery = """
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tbl_sample_detail tod
          JOIN tbl_sample to2 ON tod.sample_id = to2.id
          JOIN tbl_user ta ON to2.from_user_id = ta.id
          JOIN tbl_user ta2 ON to2.to_user_id = ta2.id
          JOIN tbl_brand tp on tod.brand_id = tp.id
        WHERE
          (ta.profile_id = :profileId OR ta2.profile_id = :profileId)
          AND (-1 = :userId OR to2.from_user_id = :userId OR to2.to_user_id = :userId)
          AND (-1 IN :sampleTypeList OR to2.sample_type IN :sampleTypeList)
          AND (-1 IN :brandIds OR tod.brand_id IN :brandIds)
          AND (-1 IN :brandCategoryIds OR tp.brand_category_id IN :brandCategoryIds)
          AND to2.created_date between :fromTime and :toTime
        """)
Page<SampleHistoryView> getSampleDetailHistory(
        @Param("userId") long userId, @Param("profileId") long profileId,
        @Param("sampleTypeList") List<Integer> sampleTypeList, @Param("brandIds") List<Short> brandIds,
        @Param("brandCategoryIds") List<Short> brandCategoryIds, @Param("fromTime") LocalDateTime fromTime,
        @Param("toTime") LocalDateTime toTime, Pageable page);

While doing the load test I have run the following query to check the long running queries and found that count takes more time (3s to 4s).
SELECT pid,client_addr,(now() - xact_start) AS TIME,state,query FROM  pg_stat_activity WHERE state IN ('active') ORDER BY TIME DESC;

Please also find the explain details as well.
Limit  (cost=1.59..431.88 rows=20 width=113) (actual time=83.950..83.993 rows=20 loops=1)
      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.59..67427.27 rows=3134 width=113) (actual time=83.949..83.990 rows=20 loops=1)
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..67341.70 rows=3134 width=97) (actual time=83.937..83.962 rows=20 loops=1)
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.87..66607.30 rows=357 width=69) (actual time=83.925..83.936 rows=4 loops=1)
                        Join Filter: ((ta.profile_id = 4) OR (ta2.profile_id = 4))
                        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 34665
                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..31828.79 rows=108554 width=56) (actual time=0.028..35.022 rows=34669 loops=1)
                              ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_06_25_tbl_sample_created_date on tbl_sample to2  (cost=0.29..29111.03 rows=108554 width=43) (actual time=0.015..17.248 rows=34669 loops=1)
                                    Index Cond: ((created_date >= '2023-06-17 19:30:12'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_date <= '2025-07-18 19:30:12'::timestamp without time zone))
                              ->  Memoize  (cost=0.29..0.32 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=34669)
                                    Cache Key: to2.from_user_id
                                    Cache Mode: logical
                                    Hits: 34664  Misses: 5  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                    ->  Index Scan using tbl_user_pkey on tbl_user ta  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=5)
                                          Index Cond: (id = to2.from_user_id)
                        ->  Index Scan using tbl_user_pkey on tbl_user ta2  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=34669)
                              Index Cond: (id = to2.to_user_id)
                  ->  Index Scan using idx_sample_detail_sample on tbl_sample_detail tod  (cost=0.42..1.73 rows=33 width=44) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=5 loops=4)
                        Index Cond: (sample_id = to2.id)
            ->  Memoize  (cost=0.30..0.34 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=20)
                  Cache Key: tod.brand_id
                  Cache Mode: logical
                  Hits: 15  Misses: 5  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
                  ->  Index Scan using tbl_brand_pkey on tbl_brand tp  (cost=0.29..0.33 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=5)
                        Index Cond: (id = tod.brand_id)
    Planning Time: 1.426 ms
    Execution Time: 84.059 ms

Database instance is db.t3.xlarge with 500GB storage.
Really appreciate your help on figuring out why this is happening
UPDATE
Please find following explain query after setting track_io_timing = on
    Limit  (cost=1.59..431.88 rows=20 width=113) (actual time=92.846..92.890 rows=20 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=129868
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.59..67427.27 rows=3134 width=113) (actual time=92.845..92.886 rows=20 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=129868
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..67341.70 rows=3134 width=97) (actual time=92.834..92.859 rows=20 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=129853
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.87..66607.30 rows=357 width=69) (actual time=92.821..92.832 rows=4 loops=1)
                    Join Filter: ((ta.profile_id = 4) OR (ta2.profile_id = 4))
                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 34665
                    Buffers: shared hit=129837
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..31828.79 rows=108554 width=56) (actual time=0.019..38.105 rows=34669 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=25830
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_06_25_tbl_sample_created_date on tbl_sample to2  (cost=0.29..29111.03 rows=108554 width=43) (actual time=0.009..16.956 rows=34669 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((created_date >= '2023-06-17 19:30:12'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_date <= '2025-07-18 19:30:12'::timestamp without time zone))
                                Buffers: shared hit=25815
                          ->  Memoize  (cost=0.29..0.32 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=34669)
                                Cache Key: to2.from_user_id
                                Cache Mode: logical
                                Hits: 34664  Misses: 5  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=15
                                ->  Index Scan using tbl_user_pkey on tbl_user ta  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=5)
                                      Index Cond: (id = to2.from_user_id)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=15
                    ->  Index Scan using tbl_user_pkey on tbl_user ta2  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=34669)
                          Index Cond: (id = to2.to_user_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=104007
              ->  Index Scan using idx_sample_detail_sample on tbl_sample_detail tod  (cost=0.42..1.73 rows=33 width=44) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=5 loops=4)
                    Index Cond: (sample_id = to2.id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=16
        ->  Memoize  (cost=0.30..0.34 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=20)
              Cache Key: tod.brand_id
              Cache Mode: logical
              Hits: 15  Misses: 5  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
              Buffers: shared hit=15
              ->  Index Scan using tbl_brand_pkey on tbl_brand tp  (cost=0.29..0.33 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=5)
                    Index Cond: (id = tod.brand_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=15
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=86
Planning Time: 1.337 ms
Execution Time: 92.950 ms

SECOND UPDATE
CPU utilization is going to 100% while running load test on above mentioned API. Please find following screenshot of CPU utilization.


3 to 4 seconds vs 84 milliseconds, are we looking at the same query?

Check if the machine is overloaded. Get an execution plan from a slow execution (ideally with track_io_timing = on) and add ir to the question.

profile_id is clearly not indexed or part of any other index used.

@FrankHeikens yes it that time for the count query while load testing and there is a index CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_user_profile_id ON tbl_user USING btree (profile_id)

@LaurenzAlbe please find updated execution plan results. not sure whether is it with database cpu capacity related issue

I wouldn't call that slow, but your problem is this join filter: Join Filter: ((ta.profile_id = 4) OR (ta2.profile_id = 4)). You should split the query into two queries, one for each branch of the OR, and UNION the results.

Is it a VM ? Does resources of the VM is fixed ? Does your ESX has no overload ?

@SQLpro resources are fixed and issue is the CPU utilization. please find the attached screenshot as well. currently having 2 cores and 16GB memory for this RDS instance

@iuhettiarachchi this does not indicate if the VM has fixed resources or not. You must go to the ESC platform to see if checkbox "reserve all guest memory" is checked and also if the amount of Mhz for CPU is reserved to 95% of the total of core * nominal speed. If not, ressources attributed to the VM is ballooning...
